# Why does playwright think the ARIA role for a <th> tag is `cell`?

Tags: playwright, wai-aria, playwright-typescript

Playwright emphasizes using "user-facing attributes and explicit contracts such as `page.getByRole()`" to locate items on a page. I want to locate a `th` tag on my page. Chrome's DevTools has an Accessibility tab that says the `th` on my page is a `columnheader` role, and [MDN's technical summary for the `th` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#technical_summary) says it should be a `columnheader` role, so I would expect `getByRole('columnheader')` to find my `th`.

It turns out that Playwright can't find it when I use `columnheader`. Instead it suggests I use the `cell` role.  And indeed that works. But it seems that Playwright is just wrong here, as that doesn't agree with MDN and Chrome. Why does Playwright think the ARIA role for a `th` tag is `cell`?

If you want to play along, here's some simple markup you can use:

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>Value</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Or here's a table that demonstrates a `columnheader` role for the `th`:

| Header |
| --- |
| Value |

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/cfefac74ab9c5b588af92b1f993073ba3c113e45/packages/playwright-core/src/server/injected/roleUtils.ts#L148), the `th` tag need `scope='col'` to be located by role `'columnheader'`. It makes sense since `th` could potentially be either `'rowheader'` or `'columnheader'`.

It also complies with the [W3C's Accessibility API Mappings specifications](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-th):

> HTML Specification    th (is not a column header, row header, column group header or row group header, and ancestor table element has table role)
> [wai-aria-1.2]: **cell role**

Comment: Would you be able to assist me in understanding why linking to 3.4.132 ("is not a column header, row header, column group header or row group header, and ancestor table element has table role") declaring it's a cell is more correct in this case than 3.4.134 ("is a column header or column group header") declaring its a column header? In my table the th is in the thead, and is definitely on top of a column. Why can Chrome determine the th is a columnheader, while Playwright needs to be told (via scope="col")?

Comment: Looking at the definition of a column header in [3.4.134 of W3C's Accessibility API Mappings specifications:](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#column-header), it must have either the col role or to be in auto state, which is unfamiliar to me. It's plausible that Playwright's implementation may be too simplistic in this regard.

Comment: That is what I see too. And building on your point, from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element, "The attribute's missing value default and invalid value default are both the auto state."

Comment: I think you are correct, might be worth filing an issue on this.

Comment: On the other hand, MDN's Accessibility's docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/columnheader_role#best_practices)  for best practices for the `columnheader` role say that `<th scope="col">` is the preferred way. It's not clear to me what is correct.